# How to pass the String into combo box?

Tags: java, string, combobox

I would like to update my list in combo box in GUI each time when something happen.
I am receiving a new list from a server as `String`. My list in combo box type `static String unitsList[]`. I have tried array conversion and splitting using comma delimiter.

How to pass the `String` into combo box?

Comment: Is this AWT or Swing or..?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I was asking which type of **components** were being used.  Don't mix the two together.  And I will repeat.. **For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).**

Answer (score 1):

Simple...

```
JComboBox /*varname*/ = new JComboBox(/*string array here?*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `addItem()`

E.g. if your comboBox is called "Example"

```
Example.addItem("Test");
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if you meant a String array or String, since your syntax looks slightly wrong. If you need a String array, then @Tdorno looks correct.